# How to set $base_url when running a site in a subdomain?

Tags: uri

I just uploaded a site to a remote server. The url is a subdomain: mySubdomain.myDomain.com.

The site just shows the front page. If I tried to navigate to other page (ex.: el-graner) I get this message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /ca/el-graner was not found on this server.
```

I set the $base_url variable in sites/default/settings.php in this way, then clear all caches...but not working at all.

```
$base_url = 'http://mySubdomain.myDomain.com';
```

What are the settings I need to do when running a drupal site in a subdomain?

Comment: When you hover over the link (or view source), is it "/ca/el-graner" or "/el-graner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .htaccess file, you should also uncomment the following line. (Remove the *#* character.)

```
# RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Needing to set `RewriteBase` is not strictly true for subdomains.  It really depends on how you have Apache configured to serve up the subdomain.  I have never needed it when the subdomain in a normal `VirtualHost` situation with `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` explicitly defined.

Comment: I was an typo error in the .htaccess file. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing cache after uploading to remote server?

If it didn't help, you could try installing Global Redirect module. It may resolve your problem, or at least can help reduce the possibility of problems created by path aliases.